# How to join a list of filtered duplicated files with their corresponding paths?

Tags: python, list, scripting

I have created a `script` to check for all files on my repository ending with `.js` extension. Then, it splits the files from their `path` & `return` only the duplicated files.

This is working fine, but I want to join the duplicated files returned `list` with their respective `paths`. For simplicity, I have only included a `list` representing all files on my project:

```
// a list representing all my project files ending with .js extension

filePaths = [
  'integration/appointment/user-daily.js',
  'integration/scheduler/user-daily.js', 
  'integration/time-off-types/time-off-types.js',
  'integration/billing-types/billing-cycle.js',
  'integration/accounting/client-yearly.js',
  'integration/exports/client-weekly.js',
  'integration/user-schedule/client-weekly.js',
]

fileNames = []

for i in range(len(filePaths)):
    fileNames.append((filePaths[i].split('/'))[-1])

    duplicatedFiles = filter(lambda rec : fileNames.count(rec) >1 ,fileNames)


print(duplicatedFiles)
```

This is the current `output` that I'm getting:

```
['user-daily.js', 'user-daily.js', 'client-weekly.js', 'client-weekly.js']
```

But I need to get their full `paths`:

```
['integration/appointment/user-daily.js', 'integration/appointment/user-daily.js', 'integration/user-schedule/client-weekly.js', 'integration/user-schedule/client-weekly.js']
```

I have tried joining their `path`, but I'm not able to get it to work.

Comment: Might be just me but I find this question extremely confusing. You say that you split the files from their path, and now you want to join them with their path again? Why then split in the first place?

Comment: can you check if your expected results again? they all have the same path. Is this what you wanted? thanks

Comment: @timgeb yes I agree it might be confusing... I have to separate the files from their path because their paths might be different, but I just want to check if I get duplicated files with the same name in the project regardless of the path. If I keep the path before while doing the check I'll never get those duplicated files.

Comment: So the question is just how to get the strings in `filePath` where the basename exists more than once?

Comment: @timgeb what am I trying to achieve is to get all duplicated name files within my project regardless of their path. Is it clearer? Maybe my approach is not correct, but basically that's why I am trying to accomplish

Comment: Also why is `'integration/exports/client-weekly.js'` not in the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
from collections import defaultdict
filename_to_paths = defaultdict(list)

for filePath in filePaths:
    key = filePath.split('/')[-1]
    filename_to_paths[key].append(filePath)

duplicates = []
for files in filename_to_paths.values():
    if len(files) > 1:
        duplicates.extend(files)
print(duplicates)
```

Output:

```
['integration/appointment/user-daily.js', 'integration/scheduler/user-daily.js', 'integration/exports/client-weekly.js', 'integration/user-schedule/client-weekly.js']
```

Comment: Bruh! That's exactly what I have been looking for! Thank you so much! Can you explain me a bit the code?

Comment: Sure. Create a mapping from the filename to the list of paths that end with the filename.
Then, iterate through the map to locate duplicates. If there is more than 1 filepath per value, then, they are duplicates. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a dict to track the file names first, like this

```
    filePaths = [
        "integration/appointment/user-daily.js",
        "integration/scheduler/user-daily.js",
        "integration/time-off-types/time-off-types.js",
        "integration/billing-types/billing-cycle.js",
        "integration/accounting/client-yearly.js",
        "integration/exports/client-weekly.js",
        "integration/user-schedule/client-weekly.js",
    ]

    fileNames = {}
    for fp in filePaths:
        name = (fp.split("/"))[-1]
        fileNames[name] = fileNames[name] + 1 if name in fileNames else 1

    duplicatedFiles = list(filter(lambda x: fileNames[x.split("/")[-1]] > 1, filePaths))
    print(duplicatedFiles)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
>>> import os
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> basenames = {full: os.path.split(full)[1] for full in filePaths}
>>> counts = Counter(basenames.values())
>>> [full for full, base in basenames.items() if counts[base] > 1]
['integration/appointment/user-daily.js', 'integration/scheduler/user-daily.js', 'integration/exports/client-weekly.js', 'integration/user-schedule/client-weekly.js']
```

Please compare with your desired result, I think it's wrong.